# Why does this code crash when ran?

Tags: visual-c++, crash, dllimport, dllexport, xbox360

I am making an application for xbox 360 that will import functions which were exported from a system dll and call them when needed.  I thought I did everything right as far as exporting then importing the functions, but it crashes on a single line of code.

I started by defining the functions inside of the system dll as follows:

```
void (__cdecl *SV_GameSendServerCommand)(int Client, int Type, char *Command) = (void(__cdecl * )(int, int, char * ))0x82254940;
bool (__cdecl *Dvar_GetBool)(char *Dvar) = (bool(__cdecl * )(char * ))0x8229EF58;
```

I created a .def file to export the functions while assigning their ordinals:

```
LIBRARY testdll
EXPORTS
    SV_GameSendServerCommand    @1
    Dvar_GetBool                @2
```

I built the system dll and placed the resulting testdll.lib in the folder where my application's source code was.  I then placed the following in stdafx.h of that application:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "testdll.lib")
```

I prototyped the functions to be imported and used a function called resolveFunct to get the addresses of the imported functions.

```
void (__cdecl *SV_GameSendServerCommand)(int Client, int Type, char *Command);
bool (__cdecl *Dvar_GetBool)(char *Dvar);

UINT32 resolveFunct(char* modname, UINT32 ord)
{
    UINT32 ret=0, ptr2=0;
    HANDLE ptr32 = 0;
    ret = XexGetModuleHandle(modname, &ptr32);
    if(ret == 0)
    {
        ret = XexGetProcedureAddress(ptr32, ord, &ptr2);
        if(ptr2 != 0)
            return ptr2;
    }
    return 0; // function not found
}
```

When I tried printing the address of the function, it was successful and read 0x91F8BF54.  I did this twice, and it printed both times.  The proceeding line of code caused my application to crash.

```
DWORD WINAPI Start(LPVOID)
{
    for(;;)
    {
        if(!LoadedUp)
        {
            printf("0x%p\n", resolveFunct("testdll.xex",2));
            if(Dvar_GetBool == NULL)
            {
                printf("0x%p\n", resolveFunct("testdll.xex",2));
                Dvar_GetBool = (bool(__cdecl*)(char*))resolveFunct("testdll.xex",2);
```

I don't understand why this line of code causes my program to crash, though.  Any answers/suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: If you have an import lib why are you linking explicitly?

Comment: Besides poor programming practice, I don't see how that is an issue?

Comment: I'm trying to understand why you are doing what you are doing. Often it pays to dig a bit deeper when a question is asked. Often what is revealed can be significant. Anyway, sounds like you don't need my help. Good luck.

Comment: Because of the `#pragma` directive, `resolveFunct` is not necessary. Just declare the funcs and then call them. Although, the 1st snippet (manually assigning an address to a func ptr is kind of unusual - and a perfect candidate for crash on my opinion). It's the function call (or the next line) that crashes right?